# Why might exec.Command.Start() hang on darwin?

Tags: go, fork, exec, race-condition, darwin

I get occasional hangs running a particular development version of a program that doesn't seem to hang using the official version. The dev version differs mainly in that it brings in a lot more Go std libraries, which (for the most part) it does not exercise; so the executable is larger, plus static-var and init() initializations are done, which might increase the likelihood of hitting some race condition.

`git bisect run` identified the (golang) culprit as `6becb033341602f2df9d7c55cc23e64b925bbee2`:

```
Author: Ian Lance Taylor <iant@golang.org>
Date:   Thu Apr 11 16:53:11 2019 -0700

[...]

    runtime: switch to using new timer code

diff --git a/src/runtime/time.go b/src/runtime/time.go
index fea5d6871c..db48a932d4 100644
--- a/src/runtime/time.go
+++ b/src/runtime/time.go
@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@ import (
 )

 // Temporary scaffolding while the new timer code is added.
-const oldTimers = true
+const oldTimers = false

 // Package time knows the layout of this structure.
 // If this struct changes, adjust ../time/sleep.go:/runtimeTimer.
```

Having glanced at the differences this small change introduces, I'm leaning strongly towards there being some race condition in this "new timer code" and/or code it enables.

Whether via Ctrl-\ (**SIGQUIT**) or `delve attach`, the culprit always seems to be the `cmd.Start()` call here:

```
func sh(dir string, stdin io.Reader, stdout io.Writer, stderr io.Writer, name string, args []string) Object {
cmd := exec.Command(name, args...)
cmd.Dir = dir
cmd.Stdin = stdin

var stdoutBuffer, stderrBuffer bytes.Buffer
if stdout != nil {
    cmd.Stdout = stdout
} else {
    cmd.Stdout = &stdoutBuffer
}
if stderr != nil {
    cmd.Stderr = stderr
} else {
    cmd.Stderr = &stderrBuffer
}

err := cmd.Start()
PanicOnErr(err)
```

The stack traces from there look quite similar, until **syscall/exec_unix.go** (in the Go source tree) is reached. Then, in Delve, it's the **forkAndExecInChild()** call that seems to hang, while Ctrl-\ shows the **readlen()** call as hung:

```
// Kick off child.
pid, err1 = forkAndExecInChild(argv0p, argvp, envvp, chroot, dir, attr, sys, p[1])
if err1 != 0 {
    err = Errno(err1)
    goto error
}
ForkLock.Unlock()

// Read child error status from pipe.
Close(p[1])
n, err = readlen(p[0], (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&err1)), int(unsafe.Sizeof(err1)))
Close(p[0])
if err != nil || n != 0 {
```

The `forkAndExecInChild()` code seems to be hung at `exec_darwin.go:206`, which is a syscall to `libc_dup2_trampoline` within a loop. Assuming that's just a call to `dup2()`, I can't think of any reason it'd hang; but I've "caught" a hung test run there (and nowhere else) at least twice, via `delve`, though perhaps that's just an artifact of using `delve attach <pid> ...` versus Ctrl-\ (**SIGQUIT**)?

I've debugged and fixed various issues around such activities over the years (ok, decades), but am relatively new to the Go ecosystem, and don't want to submit a bug report before I have some understanding of what's going on.

In particular, **Cmd.Start()** is documented thusly:

> Start starts the specified command but does not wait for it to complete.

So, on the face of it, it seems strange, if not outright buggy, that these hangs seem to point to that very call as the culprit. I.e. if it doesn't wait, why would it hang? Perhaps what looks like a direct OS call actually checks with the Go threads mechanism before or after the underlying OS call, and is getting hung there.

The problem shows up when running the test suite, which normally takes about 12 seconds to run. I've run this in loops lasting roughly 5 hours to do the `git bisect run`; though it often triggers within 15 minutes, I've seen it take over 3 hours to do so.

If anyone wants to delve (ha!) more deeply into this and maybe try to reproduce it, the program I'm working on is "Joker", and here's the development version (my fork):

https://github.com/jcburley/joker/ (See branch `gostd`; build via `./run.sh`.)

The problem occurs (occasionally), on OS X, when running `./all-tests.sh`. So far, the hangs have happened only when that script runs `./flag-tests.sh` or `./linter-tests.sh`, not yet `./eval-tests.sh` (which seems strange as well, since that always gets run first due to the alphabetical ordering).

The same test suite ran in a loop on my Ubuntu Linux (Ryzen 3) dev box, without hanging, for over 24 hours. Windows 7 looping has been going on for several hours as well, with no hang so far.

REPRO UPDATES:

- Repros (fairly quickly so far) with master as of `6a569f243e028f823a9f20bfd9da7bdfab8699a4`
- `git bisect run` identified the (golang) culprit as `6becb033341602f2df9d7c55cc23e64b925bbee2`; double-checked that and previous commit (by running five instances of the latter for many hours), looks like a solid result
- No repro after many hours on Ubuntu Linux Ryzen 3 (amd64-linux) and on Windows 7 (amd64-windows, 2011-era i7 box)
- No repro after many hours on OS X testing against official Joker
- No repro (after several hours) with 1.13.10

The Joker executable is much bigger for the dev version compared to the official (master/released) version; though most of that additional code is unexercised by this little test suite, it's possible some init() or static-var-init code, being run due to additional Go std libraries (packages) being pulled in, could contribute moreso (if not entirely) than sheer size and size-related issues by dint of launching additional go and/or OS threads, increasing contention, etc.

Comment: Did you consider writing a script for [git bisect run](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_run) and bisect the Go source code against the same version of your program ? Advantage is that it would run completely unattended...

Comment: And BTW, this is a very well written question! +1 !

Comment: I'm working on narrowing this down somehow. It's more challenging due to the lack of a simple yes/no test: besides the sheer scale of building all of Go for my Macs (need to learn how best to automate this), I'd need to then use the resulting build to build my program and then run the test suite repeatedly "N" times before deciding it worked.

Comment: (Edited to include results of repro efforts.)

Comment: Assuming this problem was introduced in Go 1.14 (which it seems to be ATM), I think the next step would indeed be the **git bisect run** approach @marco.m suggested. (I've set that up only once or twice, and it's been a few years now, compounding the issues mentioned in my above comment...but I do have a "spare" Mac Mini to use for that effort, leaving my MacBook Pro for my day-to-day work.)

Comment: It might actually be more interesting, and easier, to (manually) shave off most/all of those unneeded Go std libraries from the generated Joker executable and see whether that makes the problem go away. If it does, I wonder if a similar bisection over the included libraries would be more immediately fruitful? Not if it's just a size issue, I guess; but an init() or similar issue might take less time to spot than **git bisect run**.

Comment: `git bisect run` has proved both fruitful and quite suggestive. I'll think about (and maybe investigate) this more and probably submit a formal bug report within a day or two.

Comment: Good to hear this!

Comment: Update: Submitted https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38824 after reproducing the problem in a small test program (Joker no longer needed at all) and, after bisecting the set of imports my Joker fork pulls in, narrowed them down to just the `plugin` package that seems to be interacting improperly with the new timing code and/or the `os/exec` code.

Comment: Very good detective work! I appreciate the fact that you managed to find a very small test program (I saw it) to show the problem. I am following over there.

Comment: I have seen exec.Command.Start() hang on darwin on go1.12.9

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a reproducible test case? I doubt I'll have the time to pursue this myself, but it could help anyone else investigating this bug (and maybe yours is a different one, since mine seems to have shown up only as of Go 1.14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug on Go for MacOS and got fixed in https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/372798/

For affected Go versions prior to the fix, the workaround is to pass `-Wl,-bind_at_load` to the linker, which can be done by invoking go with `-ldflags="-extldflags=-Wl,-bind_at_load"`